# How to clone Hibernate sources using Egit (Eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, git, maven, egit

I need help using Egit (Eclipse git integration capabilities). My goal is to have [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org) [sources](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core.git) in my local Eclipse. Eventually I aim for running their tests, doing some changes in the sources, issuing a git pull request (patch), etc.

**Can someone explain how to clone Hibernate sources and have them as Java Project(s) in Eclipse?**

---

All I can achieve myself is to have the sources cloned (as needed) to some specified path (the suggested path is outside of the workspace directory). Then I am puzzled trying to convert the structure into Java projects in Eclipse. I try different ways to import the project(s) using `File | Import` (e.g. Existing projects into workspace) or linking sources into a new created Java project. The problem seems to be the Hibernate sources are not a single maven project (not quite sure about this one either, I am new to maven) and probably not an Eclipse project at all, so Eclipse doesn't recognize the source structure at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it has both maven and ant builds, so you can generate Eclipse projects with both of these.

For maven you have 2 options:

1. Run [mvn eclipse:eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) to generate
   eclipse project artifacts and then
   import existing projects.
2. Install [m2Eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) and import Existing Maven
       Project.  This is the preferred
       approach when working with Maven and
       Eclipse.

For ant, **New project->Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile**

Comment: I've used the recommended Maven option (your second point) and it has definitely helped me to make some progress. Thanks. I knew it was something obvious for Maven / Git / whatever experts.